# instagram api APIAgeGatedError not in the document

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

when I try to get few people profile use instagram api  it shows error message   APIAgeGatedError, what does this mean? how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation about this exception, but I think this problem is related with your IP, I changed IP-adress and problem was solved. Or try to use proxy-server.

Answer (score 0):

The APIAgeGatedError type error is generated because the content from the requested profile is restricted to a minimum age. You can't reach the content for sure with your "general token". Perhaps with an token that has been authorized from the page you are trying to get content from. However Instagram has no provided documentation about this.